# What is the proper way to use Ninject with WebServiceHost

Tags: wcf, ninject

What is the proper way to use Ninject with WebServiceHost (when hosting in IIS)

Please note that I have NO .svc file and do not want one.  So I have extensionless url's.  I am using Ninject to inject repo, etc. to the service.  While it *works* I cant remember how I did it before and the way I am doing it now is wrong - its actually working like a self hosted - I need the service to participate in the IIS pipeline (use same port, startup/shutdown with the AppPool)...

I added a reference to Ninject.Extensions.WCF which created NinectWebCommon.cs in my App_Start folder.  Within that, I am wiring up the service as follows (but I dont want to specify url/port and I want it to participate in the proper life cycle)

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    var port = 8080;
    var uri = new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}:{1}/api", Environment.MachineName, port));

    var baseAddr = new Uri[] { uri };
    var binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None);
    var endPoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(MyServiceClassHere))
        , binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));

    kernel.Bind<IProjectRepository>().To<MyRepo>();

    kernel.Bind<WebServiceHost>().To<NinjectWebServiceHost>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("serviceType", typeof(MyServiceClassHere))
        .WithConstructorArgument("baseAddresses", baseAddr);

    var webBehavior = new WebHttpBehavior() { HelpEnabled = true };
    endPoint.Behaviors.Add(webBehavior);

    _host = kernel.Get<WebServiceHost>();
    _host.AddServiceEndpoint(endPoint);
    _host.Open();
}
```

Can you please help me with the best practice for wiring up the service using Ninject.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post helped me get Ninject up and running in my WCF service hosted in IIS:
http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/08/16/dependency-injection-ninject-wcf-service.aspx

I had to override the Load method on the NinjectModule:

```
public class WCFNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
       Bind<IProjectRepository>().To<MyRepo>();
    }
}
```

and then in the global.asax, I had to override the CreateKernel() method.

```
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
            StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new WCFNinjectModule());
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            return kernel;
    }
```